# can't see the file in parse data browser

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a simple file upload and associate the file with the current user. 
I followed the guide on parse.com and checked with several questions on here with no luck.

The saveinBackground operation is successful, no exceptions are being thrown but I can't see the file in Parse.com data browser.

Here's my code.

```
        final long time1 = Time;
    //Image part
    //upload the .jpg file for user's history
    //Parse
    byte[] data = filePath.getBytes();
    final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("asdasd.jpg", data);
    file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // Handle success or failure here ...
            if ( e == null){
                ParseObject rentedTime = new ParseObject("Time");
                rentedTime.put("duration", renttime1);
                rentedTime.put("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                rentedTime.put("id", id);
                rentedTime.put("image", file);
                rentedTime.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null)
                            Log.d("upload successful" + file.getName(), null);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.d("terrible", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, new ProgressCallback() {
        public void done(Integer percentDone) {
            // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
        }
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you created the `image` column in the Parse Class, and have you set it to type `File`?

Comment: what is filePath?  it doesn't appear to be a variable in the code.. what is the value of it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are NOT uploading the file..see

```
 byte[] data = filePath.getBytes();
```

just getting the bytes from the file path wont work reasonably.

First get the bitmap and then convert it to byte[] see how..

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
byte[] data  = getBytes(bitmap);

private byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    byte[] data = outputStream.toByteArray();

    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

And you can now use the data..

```
final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("asdasd.png", data);
```

I've changed the file name to .png format if you wish ti save in jpg format then compress in .JPG format as well.

Hope you find this helpful! :)